# when to go from java to android

Tags: android

I am currently reading beginner programing with java for dummies second edition by barry burd, when i finish should I start learning android (if so any recommendations) or more java (again recomendations greatly appreciated) tyvm in advance

Comment: If you read any of the questions here, there are plenty of people who start trying to write android apps without knowing a single programming language or knowing what a class is.

Comment: Ugh, I would **not** recommend the "For Dummies" series to learn programming. Dummies do not write good code. There are [much](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+book) [better](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75102/) [resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772802/) out there for learning Java. The [Head First](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0596004656/?tag=stackoverfl08-20) books are decent, as are the [Oracle Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of your personal motivations, but I would say that java is always a better choice for learning your way around. In Java, you can easily run and test your program, without having to worry with load times of emulators or having to look among the emulator's log window for your own occasional debug messages.

Doing so will not be limiting to you, in the sense that Java is a universe in itself (as is Android).

Android is a mobile platform easy to get started with though, but having a stronger background of how things work in Java will benefit you there, and that background will eventually be faster to achieve by using Java for a start.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how comfortable you are with Java at the end of the book. Much more important than just reading a book, is actually writing some code. Try to think of something that interests you, and write a program for it (400+ lines of code), and see if you feel like you're not having much trouble. If you are, more java, if not, you can go ahead and try the android API. Its not easy, mind you.